# How do I automate file upload in cucumber with Ruby if the upload file is a button tag

Tags: ruby, file, upload, cucumber, watir

How do I automate file upload in cucumber with ruby if the upload file is a button tag. I tried to convert the type to file with the script:

```
@browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('elementid').setAttribute('type', 'file');") 
@browser.div(:class => "classname").file_field.set(file.path)
```

Then I get the error:

```
unable to locate element, using `{:tag_name=>"input", :type=>"file"}`
```

The error occurs as the tag name in my application is `<button>`.

How do I handle this, any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<button type="button" id="pickfiles" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'disabled': noRuntime}" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;"> Select file </button>
```

Comment: we need the html of the page.

Comment: Here is the page HTML: <button type="button" id="pickfiles" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-class="{'disabled': noRuntime}" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">
                        Select file
                    </button>

Comment: subhashree patra: when adding HTML or code, it's better to edit the original question so that all the information is in one place and properly formatted.  FYI.

Comment: Edited the original question to add the HTML. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is the button triggering a regular file type input - ie is the end result just a population of a `<input type="file">`? I think you need to provide a working example of the entire file upload process.